# Print PDF in A5 size in landscape

Tags: ios, swift, pdf, uiprintinteractioncntrler

I am currently trying to print an PDF from my iPad through AirPrint. I got it all right when I print the PDF directly, in A4 size and portrait.

However, now I want the PDF printed to be in A5 size and is in portrait, like half the size of A4 paper which I can't make it now. Anyone got idea about this, either I should resize the the PDF file (not preferable) or there is other way to done that

Im using `UIPrintInteractionController` and it's delegate to print, while the source is from `viewPrintFormatter` from webView that load the PDF.

PageRenderer:

```
    let fmt = webView.viewPrintFormatter()

    // 2. Assign print formatter to UIPrintPageRenderer

    let render = UIPrintPageRenderer()
    render.addPrintFormatter(fmt, startingAtPageAtIndex: 0)

    // 3. Assign paperRect and printableRect

    let page = CGRect(x: 0, y: 0, width:595.2, height: 841.8) // A4, 72 dpi
    let printable = CGRectInset(page, 0, 0)

    render.setValue(NSValue(CGRect: page), forKey: "paperRect")
    render.setValue(NSValue(CGRect: printable), forKey: "printableRect")

    // 4. Create PDF context and draw

    let pdfData = NSMutableData()
    UIGraphicsBeginPDFContextToData(pdfData, CGRectZero, nil)

    for i in 1...render.numberOfPages() {

        UIGraphicsBeginPDFPage();
        let bounds = UIGraphicsGetPDFContextBounds()
        render.drawPageAtIndex(i - 1, inRect: bounds)
    }

    UIGraphicsEndPDFContext();
```

Then save it as physical file:

```
    let documentsPath = NSSearchPathForDirectoriesInDomains(.DocumentDirectory, .UserDomainMask, true)[0]

    let url = NSURL(fileURLWithPath: "\(documentsPath)/file.pdf")
    pdfData.writeToFile("\(documentsPath)/file.pdf", atomically: true)
```

And finally print it:

```
        if UIPrintInteractionController.canPrintURL(url) {
            let printInfo = UIPrintInfo(dictionary: nil)
            printInfo.jobName = url.lastPathComponent!
            printInfo.outputType = .Grayscale
            printInfo.orientation = .Landscape

            let printController = UIPrintInteractionController.sharedPrintController()
            printController.printInfo = printInfo
            printController.showsPaperSelectionForLoadedPapers = true

            printController.showsNumberOfCopies = true
            printController.delegate = self
            printController.printingItem = url

            printController.presentAnimated(true, completionHandler: nil)
        }
```

Comment: If you would show us some code so we can see how you are doing this, you might get useful comments on that. But in general I would think that UIPrintPageRenderer would do the trick as you can define how the content would be output (which would mean you can scale your incoming PDF file while you place it on the printed page).

Comment: @DavidvanDriessche I had added the code. And for the page renderer, even if I set it to A5 size, it still printing it vertically in A4 paper with smaller size. But I want it to be in A5 or half the page of A4 horizontally.

Comment: Or do you have any suggestion about the setting? because im setting it in A4 size so when it save to PDF it looks nicer.

Answer (score 3):

You can change the "paper size" of the PDF by setting the second parameter of the graphics context call.

```
UIGraphicsBeginPDFContextToData(data, CGRect(x: 0, y: 0, width: 792, height: 612), nil)
```

**bounds**

A rectangle that specifies the default size and location of PDF pages. (This value is used as the default media box for each new page.) The origin of the rectangle should typically be (0, 0). Specifying an empty rectangle (CGRectZero) sets the default page size to 8.5 by 11 inches (612 by 792 points).